# How can I get babel to support both arrow functions and flow syntax?

Tags: babeljs

I have this code:

```
var loadTempImpersonationToken = (username: string): Promise => client({
  uri: `endpoint`,
  cache: false
})
```

As you can see, this includes both an arrow function, and flow type annotations. [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) supports arrow functions (in the es2015 & stage-0 presets) as well as stripping type annotations, in the react preset.

Simply combining the presets fails:

```
{"presets": [
    "stage-0",
    "react"
]}
```

Produces

```
Error: Parse Error: Line 1: Unexpected token : while parsing file: /Users/tmcw/src/example.js
```

How does one support these features in the same code?

Comment: That compiles fine with those presets enabled, are you sure you have configured Babel properly?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had misconfigured babel - it was reading a different `.babelrc` file than the one I had set up. Sorry for the noise!